# Conditional fragments or embedded root-containers when using Relay with React-Native

Tags: react-native, relayjs

I've got `relay` working with `react-native`, but I'm confused about how to best utilize relay routes and root containers, especially when working with a `Navigator` that renders multiple routes.

Take the following class:

```js
var Nav = React.createClass({

 renderScene(route, nav) {
   switch(route.id) {
     case 'first':
       return <First navigator={nav} />
     case 'second':
       return <Second navigator={nav} />
   }
 },

 render() {
   <Navigator
     initialRoute={{ id: 'first' }}
     renderScene={this.renderScene}
   />
 }

})


module.exports = Relay.createContainer(Nav, {   
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${First.getFragment('viewer'},
        ${Second.getFragment('viewer'}
      }
    `   
  } 
})
```

In my parent route, I then request the `User` fragment which builds the query.

The problem is that the fragment will be including those fields defined by both the `first` and `second` components, even if only one of them is being displayed at a time.

In this case should I:

1) return another `Relay.RootContainer` in the `renderScene` callback? Is it generally a bad idea to embed `Relay.RootContainers` within each-other?

```js
renderScene(route, nav) {
  switch(route.id) {
    case 'first':
      return (
        <Relay.RootContainer
           Component={First}
           route={new FirstRoute()}
           renderFetched={(data) => {
             return <First navigator={nav} {...data} />
           }}
        />
      )
  }
}
```

2) Use conditional variables to include a fragment?

```js
initialVariables: {
  first: true
},

fragments: {
  viewer: (variables) => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      ${First.getFragment('viewer').if(variables.first)
    }
  `
}
```

Or are there other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using something like this:<sup>1</sup>

```js
function matchRoute(route, map) {
  return map[route.name] ? map[route.name]() : null;
}
```

Try this:

```js
fragments: {
  viewer: (variables) => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      ${route => matchRoute(route, {
        FirstRoute: () => First.getFragment('viewer'),
        SecondRoute: () => Second.getFragment('viewer'),
      }},
    }
  `,
}
```

[1]: [medium.com/@cpojer/relay-and-routing](https://medium.com/@cpojer/relay-and-routing-36b5439bad9#eeb2)

Comment: Where is the variable `route` coming from?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/1cfd48d1df9ea726d6775931fea05bf2420c4cff/src/query/RelayQL.js#L54-L57