# Relay: Parametrize getFragment based on results of a parent query

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

My CMS returns me a list of nodes each having its own nodetype. For each nodetype I have a corresponding GraphQL type defined.

```
type getContent {
  content: [ContentNode]
}
```

I want a query like:

```
{
  content{
    contentType
    properties {
       ${ContentType.getFragment('content', type: $contentType???)}
    }
  }
}
```

ContentType would return a correct fragment definition based on type variable provided to it. But how do I get `$contentType` from parent results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have fragments that depend on actual value of the parent, because fragments are composed before the query request is actually made to server. There are two different ways to handle this, one is to have fragment vary based on variables and other is to use interface and typed fragments inside your component.

Here is a good answer showing example of using variables: [Conditional fragments or embedded root-containers when using Relay with React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577496/conditional-fragments-or-embedded-root-containers-when-using-relay-with-react-na)

For the interface solution, if you have ContentNode an interfaces with implementations like 'ContentNode1' and 'ContentNode2', then you can do something like that:

```
{
  content {
    ${ContentType.getFragment('content')}
  }
}
```

And in your ContentType component

```
fragment on ContentNode {
   contentType
   someOtherCommonField
   ... on ContentNode1 {
     someContent1Field
   }

   ... on ContentNode2 {
     someContent2Field
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great reply. I will try to explore your interfaces solution, looks really promising so far, and will mark you answer as accepted once I finally get it.

Comment: Conditional fragments won't work for me, as the route information does not contain the type of element I'm rendering (because that may be a fixed collection of elements).

But your second approach seems really cool. One question though: when doing smth like `... on ContentNode1 {`, will this fragment only be included for exactly this type? So there won't be any duplication of information returned?

Comment: s/fixed collection/mixed collection/

Comment: @Dmitry: What do you mean by duplication of information? One type can only be one implementation of a certain interface, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: yep, that's sort of what I meant. I need to try to experiment with that more, but I think that's just what I need, thus accept the answer. Thanks!